# A question on convergent sequence of positive terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following statement true:

> if $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence of positive real numbers then either there exists a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [1,∞)$ such that $\space$ lim $f(n)\Big(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-1\Big)$ exists and is non-negative or, there exists a function $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1]$ such that $\space$ lim $g(n)\Big(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-1\Big)$ exists and is non-negative.

(Here "or" does not mean that exactly one should happen.)

Comment: No: $\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}$.

Comment: @njguliyev The terms are supposed to be positive, I think.

Comment: Oh, sorry. First I wrote $\dfrac{1}{n!}$, but then added $(-1)^n$ to exclude $+\infty$ as a limit. Anyway, the statement is not true.

Comment: @ njguliyev:- I got your idea , I've edited my question slightly , you may give it a look , 'cause now $\frac1{n!}$ does not work , we may take $g(n)=\frac 1{n}$

Comment: If you take $x_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ you get $$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-1 = -\frac{1}{n^2}$$
and I do not see how you can choose $f,g$ with $f(x) > 0, g(x) > 0,$ and have a positive limit.

Comment: @ gammatester: I have not said 'strictly positive' only non-negative , and I do not have to choose both $f$ and $g$ , only one will suffice , in your case perhaps you can see there are infinitely many choices for $g$ .

Comment: @SouvikDey, you can always choose $g$ such that $g(n)\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} -1 \right) \to 0$.

Comment: @ njguliyev: May you explain why , I would invite you to write an answer.

Comment: $$g(n):=\dfrac{1/n}{\left|\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-1\right|+1}.$$

Comment: @ njguliyev: Thanks , got it .